# Uso de pilhas e passagem por referência

Tags: c, memória, referência, value, passagem-por-referência

Olá, estou fazendo um programa onde possuo uma pilha e quero reorganizar os elementos desta. Eu criei uma função que realiza isto so que a pilha original nao está sendo modificada (ela só é modificada na função mas nao é modificada na memória).
Em baixo encontra-se o codigo da função e a chamada da mesma.

```
void organizaPilha(PilhaPostagens *P, Mensagem postagem) {
CelulaMensagem *celulaAuxiliar, *celulaAuxiliar2;
PilhaPostagens pilhaAuxiliar, pilha2;
iniciaPilha(&pilhaAuxiliar);
if(verificaPilhaVazia(P)) {
  puts("Pilha Vazia, não é possivel desempilhar o item");
  return;
}
celulaAuxiliar = P->topo->proximo;
while((celulaAuxiliar->timeline.IDmensagem != postagem.IDmensagem)) {
  empilhaItem(&pilhaAuxiliar, celulaAuxiliar->timeline);
  celulaAuxiliar = celulaAuxiliar->proximo;
}
celulaAuxiliar2 = celulaAuxiliar;
while(celulaAuxiliar->proximo != NULL) {
  empilhaItem(&pilhaAuxiliar, celulaAuxiliar->proximo->timeline);
  celulaAuxiliar = celulaAuxiliar->proximo;
}
iniciaPilha(&pilha2);
celulaAuxiliar = pilhaAuxiliar.topo->proximo;
while(celulaAuxiliar != NULL) {
  empilhaItem(&pilha2, celulaAuxiliar->timeline);
  celulaAuxiliar = celulaAuxiliar->proximo;
}
empilhaItem(&pilha2, celulaAuxiliar2->timeline);
P = &pilha2;
liberaPilha(&pilhaAuxiliar);
liberaPilha(&pilha2);
}

organizaPilha(&postagens[indiceAmigos[auxiliar]], mensagemCurtida);
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a entender o porquê da pilha original nao está sendo alterada ou me dar uma dica de como resolver isso?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

A pilha original não está sendo alterada porque você está colocando as alterações em "pilha2".

Aparentemente você está tentando copiar "pilha2" para "P" no final da função.

Isso não está funcionando, primeiro porque "P" é um parâmetro, portanto é uma variável local à função, segundo porque isso só faria sentido se as pilhas tivessem sido alocadas no heap, o que não parece ser o caso, e mesmo assim, neste caso a pilha original precisaria ser desalocada.

```
void organizaPilha(PilhaPostagens *P, Mensagem postagem)
{
   CelulaMensagem *celulaAuxiliar, *celulaAuxiliar2;
   PilhaPostagens pilhaAuxiliar /*, pilha2*/;

   iniciaPilha(&pilhaAuxiliar);

   if (verificaPilhaVazia(P))
   {
      puts("Pilha Vazia, não é possivel desempilhar o item");
      return;
   }

   celulaAuxiliar = P->topo->proximo;

   while ((celulaAuxiliar->timeline.IDmensagem != postagem.IDmensagem))
   {
      empilhaItem(&pilhaAuxiliar, celulaAuxiliar->timeline);
      celulaAuxiliar = celulaAuxiliar->proximo;
   }

   celulaAuxiliar2 = celulaAuxiliar;

   while (celulaAuxiliar->proximo != NULL)
   {
      empilhaItem(&pilhaAuxiliar, celulaAuxiliar->proximo->timeline);
      celulaAuxiliar = celulaAuxiliar->proximo;
   }

// iniciaPilha(&pilha2);
   iniciaPilha(P);

   celulaAuxiliar = pilhaAuxiliar.topo->proximo;

   while (celulaAuxiliar != NULL)
   {
//    empilhaItem(&pilha2, celulaAuxiliar->timeline);
      empilhaItem(P, celulaAuxiliar->timeline);
      celulaAuxiliar = celulaAuxiliar->proximo;
   }

// empilhaItem(&pilha2, celulaAuxiliar2->timeline);
   empilhaItem(P, celulaAuxiliar2->timeline);

// P = &pilha2;

   liberaPilha(&pilhaAuxiliar);
// liberaPilha(&pilha2);
}

organizaPilha(&postagens[indiceAmigos[auxiliar]], mensagemCurtida);
```